# python string comparison function

Tags: python

```
def mystrcmp(x,y):
   print (x.lower(),y.lower())
   if(str(x.lower()) == str(y.lower())):
         print ("true")
   else:
         print ("false")

mystrcmp("python", "pTHYON")
```

This code gives incorrect output, it should give `True` but gives `False`

Comment: Why "python" should be equal "pthyon"?

Comment: Please explain your code, use proper grammar, and don't expect people to understand what the code is supposed to do without well-formed English sentences. See the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help article.

Comment: 1. There should not be a space before parenthesis in function calls. 2. Your conditional grouping characters on line 3 are redundant. 3. You *probably* want to remove the quotes around `"true"` and `"false"` and capitalize them, so they return proper values. 4. It's not working because in the last line, you spelled `"pTHYON"` wrong. It should be `"pYTHON"`.

Comment: 5.  Python `if` statements do not require parentheses around the conditional.  6.  `str(x.lower())`  - if `x` was not a `str` object then it wouldn't have a `.lower()` method.  Since `lower()` returns a string anyway, why use `str()`, except perhaps:  `str(x).lower()` ?

Comment: This line `if(str(x.lower())` is the definition of redundant work.The `.lower()` function can't be called on anything but a string, so x is already a string.  You converting it to string by the `str()` method is just useless.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You Can Use the following script to really get a `true` output

```
def mystrcmp(x,y):
        x, y = str(x),str(y)
    print(x.lower(),y.lower())
    if x.lower() == y.lower():
        print ("true")
    else:
        print ("false")

mystrcmp("python", "pYTHON")
```

Comment: thanks! I found a spelling mistake in my code. corrected it now

Answer (score 0):

i solved it, spelling mistake, Python